# Setting Marquee in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I'm trying to set **Marquee tag** attributes in my CSS. I want it to scroll down then back up again, with the height set to 100%. This is height is relative to the its parent tag which is also set to 100% relative to the **body** tag.

This is the CSS for it

```
marquee{
height:100%;
marquee-direction: down;
marquee-style: alternate;
}
```

Presently it scrolls from right to left and not on all the screen. How could I rectify this, thanks.

Or is there any JQuery plugin that could achieve a similar result?

Comment: FYI, according to MDN: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: @j08691 thanks. So does that mean I cannot use CSS, but can I use the marquee tag attributes or is that a non-standard feature too?

Comment: Essentially it's a warning not to use the marquee tag at all.

Comment: you can use CSS `animation` instead, like this http://jsfiddle.net/TQnn9/3/ I have to admit that the marquee tag is very convenient in some cases, but because it's not standard, we should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS attributes related to `marquee` have been defined in drafts only and left almost completely unimplemented. According to [Apple information](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-marquee-direction), they are supported in Safari on iOS, but only with the `-webkit-` vendor prefix. It is unlikely that this will change much, as `marquee` is generally regarded as outdated.

So if you use `marquee`, use [HTML attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0) rather than CSS properties to control how the marquee runs. Example:

```
<marquee direction=down behavior=alternate>Hello world!</marquee>
```

However, WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari) have the bug that `behavior=alternate` prevents the entire marquee effect.

Comment: Thanks, but the bug you mentioned will be a pain.